# Show that the transformation is a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that the transformation $T$ takes a $2\times 2$ matrix $A$ to it's transpose $A^t$ is a linear transformation. (make sure it preserved matrix addition and multiplication)

So I know a $2\times 2$ matrix is a square matrix and that transposing switches the rows and columns. For this should I just pick random letters to represent the items in the matrix and then show addition and multiplication are closed?

Comment: NOTE: you have to show that multiplication BY A SCALAR is preserved, not matrix multiplication (which is NOT preserved).

Comment: $(A+B)^{t}=A^t+B^t$ and $(\lambda A)^t=\lambda A^t.$

Answer (score 0):

Usually for such questions, you may proceed as follows:

You have $T$ the transformation defined for every $2 \times 2$ matrix  $A=\begin{bmatrix}  a & b  \\ c & d  \end{bmatrix}$ by 
$$ T(A)= T\Bigg(  \begin{bmatrix}  a & b  \\ c & d  \end{bmatrix}  \Bigg) =  \begin{bmatrix}  a & c  \\ b & d  \end{bmatrix}$$

You have to show that $T$ is linear, then you should show that $T$ is distributative over addition and  $T$ is homogeneuos( with repect to  scalars).

More precisely, you have to show that

1. For any two matrices  $A$ and $B$:  $$ T(A+B)=T(A) +T(B)$$
2. For any matrix $A$, and  any scalar $\alpha$: $$ T(\alpha A)=\alpha T(A)$$

Answer (score 0):

You need to show $T(c.A + B )  = c.T(A) + T(B)$

$A = \begin{bmatrix}
a_{1,1}   & a_{1,2}\\
a_{2,1}   & a_{2,2}
\end{bmatrix}$ .

$B = \begin{bmatrix}
b_{1,1}   & b_{1,2}\\
b_{2,1}   & b_{2,2}
\end{bmatrix}$ .

$cA+B = \begin{bmatrix}
ca_{1,1} +b_{1,1}  & ca_{1,2} +b_{1,2}\\
ca_{2,1} +b_{2,1}  & ca_{2,2} +b_{2,2}
\end{bmatrix}$ .

$T(cA+B) = \begin{bmatrix}
c.a_{1,1} +b_{1,1}  & c.a_{2,1} +b_{2,1}\\
c.a_{1,2} +b_{1,2}  & c.a_{2,2} +b_{2,2}
\end{bmatrix}$ =
$\begin{bmatrix}
c.a_{1,1} & c.a_{2,1}\\
c.a_{1,2}  & c.a_{2,2}
\end{bmatrix}$
$ + \begin{bmatrix}
b_{1,1}  & b_{2,1}\\
b_{1,2}  & b_{2,2}
\end{bmatrix}$ $= c.T(A) + T(B)$.